# Swapping elements in a list without using a temporary variable

Tags: python, list

```
def swap_firstandlast(list):
  list[-1],list[0] = list[0],list[-1]
  print(list)
```

When asked to swap two values I always use a temporary variable to a value and then assign it a new value until I saw this code. Can someone explain this code? Like in what order the values gets assigned. Like if `list[-1]` first gets assigned the value of list[0] then the output will be wrong right but this code works perfectly fine and I want to know how it works.

Comment: it's like you are unpacking a tuple to another, so when you set the second part of the line (list[0], list[-1]) is creating a tuple of two items then unpack them to the other tuple

Answer (score 0):

The code works because you are not modifying the two elements with two separate statements.
You have basically extracted them as a **tuple** and assigned them the values ​​currently in memory, and the values ​​in memory are not changed until the entire instruction is processed correctly.